# Can I get the Temperature from the colors matrices or the chromatic adaptation provided in the ICC Profile (meta-data) of a picture?

Tags: white-balance, icc-profile

I would like to get the temperature of a picture already taken to determine the kind of white-balance has been used.

I can only access the ICC profile.
I wanted to know if it's possible to use Red/Green/BlueMatrixColumn or chromatic adaption values in order to get the temperature of the picture ?

I maybe, should use correlated color temperature but I don't know how...

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I would like to calculate temperature programatically from the colors MatrixColumns provided in ICC profile.

Comment: Why would you like to calculate temperature programmatically from the color matrix columns provided in ICC profile? is that a thing? What does temperature have to do with color profile?

Comment: I have to compare multiple pictures of different object in order to detect their composition. I would like to get temperature from picture because the picture must be in the same white balance in order to be usable.
I would like also to have anybody able to send me photos. I didn't wanted to block people with lock white balance stuff so i wanted to convert by myself the temperatures to be the same. The color profile is the only thing that is often in png file and  I thought (maybe I over thought) that I would be able to use the chromatic adaptation matrices or the colors matrices ...

Comment: You'd probably get an answer here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision This stack is a photography stack, as in artistic photography.

Comment: @EmileRoch For a controlled scientific exercise such as this you are going to need a better selection of photos then just a bunch of people with different cameras and lighting set ups and so on.  All photos  should be shot in the same light, with the same camera and the same white balance setting and access to the metadata files.